# Сравнение данных 2-х массивов C#

Tags: c#

Дано два массива :

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\\sort", "*");
string[] dirs2 = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\\sort2", "*");
```

Внутри 1-го массива содержатся элементы: 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg.
Внутри 2-го массива содержатся элементы: 1.jpg, 2.jpg.

Нужно сравнить эти 2 массива и записать в отдельный массив элементы, которые не совпадают у этих двух массивов. 
В данном случае в отдельный массив должен записаться "3.jpg".

Comment: Думаю, с помощью вот этого: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx проще всего, ну или LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для эти целей лучше всего подойдут множества, а именно класс `HashSet<T>`.

Создаешь 2 множества, а затем с помощью `Except` вычитаешь одно множество из другого, получая значения, которых нет в другом множестве.